# Evaluating $\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (1-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}$ using Mathematica

Tags: limits, mathematica

I am trying to evaluate:
$$\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (1-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}$$
Here are my steps:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (1-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}&=\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (-n-z+1) \prod _{k=0}^{n-1} (-k-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}\\[4pt]
&=\left(\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (-n-z+1)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}\right) \lim_{z\to n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-k-z) \\[4pt]
&=(-1)^n \left(\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma(-n-z+1)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}\right) \lim_{z\to n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+z)
\end{align*}
Here is the problem, also verified by Mathematica,
$$
\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (-n-z+1)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}=1
$$
so we should expect that
\begin{align*}
(-1)^n \left(\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (-n-z+1)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}\right) \lim_{z\to n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+z)&=(-1)^n 
 \lim_{z\to n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+z)\\
&=(-1)^nn(n+1)\cdots(2n-1)\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{1\cdot2\cdots n(n+1)\cdots(2n-1)({\color{red} 2}n)}{{\color{red} 2}\cdot 1\cdot2\cdots n}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
\end{align*}
One may, then, conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (1-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
\end{align*}
But Mathematica gives
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma (1-z)}{\Gamma (1-2 z)}={(-1)^n}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
\end{align*}
Am I missing something here? Of course, there are other approaches, but I want to understand why! there is such inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

Actually $$\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma(-n-z+1)}{\Gamma(1-2z)}=2.$$ This can be shown using $$\lim_{z\to-n}(z+n)\Gamma(z)=\color{gray}{\lim_{z\to-n}\frac{\Gamma(z+n+1)}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n-1)}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$ (where $n$ is a nonnegative integer), as well as the original limit: $$\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\Gamma(1-z)}{\Gamma(1-2z)}=2\lim_{z\to n}\frac{\big((1-z)+(n-1)\big)\Gamma(1-z)}{\big((1-2z)+(2n-1)\big)\Gamma(1-2z)}\\{}=2\frac{(-1)^{n-1}/(n-1)!}{(-1)^{2n-1}/(2n-1)!}=(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!}.$$

Comment: Essentially you exploit the poles of the gamma function at negative numbers, that is the idea if I get it

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\Gamma(-n-z+1)}{\Gamma(1-2z)} =2$$ I don't know how you "verified" the wrong limit since you don't share your math nor your code.

Comment: In[96]:= Limit[Gamma[-z - n + 1]/Gamma[1 - 2*z], z -> n]

Out[96]= 1

Comment: @NasserSaad Limit[Gamma[-z - n + 1]/Gamma[1 - 2*z], z -> n, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]=2.

Comment: @NasserSaad Did you expected Mathematica to guess that $n$ is an integer just by the name of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the value of *n*. If we plot the limit for various

*n* = {-2.00, -1.75, -1.50, ... 2.00}

from

*z* = [*n*-1,*n*+1]

we see that the limit flips back and forth between 1 and 2.

```
Table[
    Plot[Gamma[-z - n + 1]/Gamma[1 - 2*z],
    {z, n - 1, n + 1},
    PlotRange -> {{n - 1, n + 1}, {-5, 3}},
    PlotLabel -> Style["n = " <> ToString[n], 18],
    PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2],
    ImageSize -> Automatic -> 200,
    Epilog -> {
        {Black, Dashed, Line[{{n - 1, 2}, {n + 0.8, 2}}]},
        {Text[Style["1", Red, 18], {n + 0.9, 1}]},
        {Black, Dashed, Line[{{n - 1, 1}, {n + 0.8, 1}}]},
        {Text[Style["2", Red, 18], {n + 0.9, 2}]},
        {Red, Line[{{n, -5}, {n, 3}}]},
        {Text[Style["z=n", Red, 18], {n + 0.25, -4}]},
    }], {n, -2, 2, 0.25}]
```

(I'd attach an image, but my account is too new)

We see that for *n* = {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0,...} the limit is 2. Where all other values of *n* yield a limit of 1.

Notably, (and likely the cause of confusion on this post) if n=0, it will yield a limit of 1, where all other positive integers yield a limit of 2. So the result will change depending on if your assumption permits *n* to be zero or not.

You can also test this with the following limits:

```
In: n=.;

In: Limit[Gamma[-z - n + 1]/Gamma[1 - 2*z], z -> n,  Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0]

Out: 1

In: Limit[Gamma[-z - n + 1]/Gamma[1 - 2*z], z -> n,  Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]

Out: 2
```

There seems to be an issue with Mathematica. It should be giving a conditional answer for `Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0` depending on if n is zero, or greater than zero... but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 1$, using Legendre duplication formula,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\Gamma(1-n-z)}{\Gamma(1-2z)} &=\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\pi}{\sin(n\pi+z\pi)\Gamma(n+z)}\times \frac{\sin(2\pi z)\Gamma(2z)}{\pi}\\
&=(-1)^n\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\sin(2\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}\times \frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(n+z)}\\
&=(-1)^n\lim_{z\to n} \frac{2\cos(2\pi z)}{\cos(\pi z)}\times \frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(n+z)}\qquad ( L'Hospital's ~rule)\\
&=2\frac{(-1)^{2n}(-1)^n}{(-1)^n}\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(n+z)}\\
&=2\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(n+z)}=2
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to n} \frac{\Gamma(1-n-z)}{\Gamma(1-2z)} =\begin{cases} 1,\qquad if\quad n=0,\\
2,\qquad if\quad n\geq 1,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}